# Modify date format in-place through `sed` command

Tags: shell-script, sed, date

I'm trying to modify the dates in a text in place where there are as `2016-Dec-24` or `2016-12-24` and I have to replace them like `24/12/2016`.

Is there any way I can use `sed -i` to do this?

Input example:

> Holiday or Observance Religious Group Dates   Additional Notes
>   *Rosh Hashanah (New Year) Jewish  25-Sep-2014 - 26-Sep-2014   Designated non-work day for observers Navaratri/Dassehra    Hindu   Sept. 2014-Oct-03
>
> *Yom Kippur (Day of Atonement)    Jewish  2014-Oct-04,    Designated non-work day for observers
>
> Sponsored Conferences Title   Location    Conference Date 2017 IEEE Sensors
>   Applications Symposium (SAS)  United States   2017-03-13, 2017-03-14,
>   2017-03-15 2017 IEEE International Symposium on Medical Measurements
>   and Applications (MeMeA)  United States   2017-05-07 to 2017-05-10 2017
>   IEEE International Instrumentation and Measurement Technology
>   Conference (I

That's what I've tried so far.

```
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(01|Jan\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(02|Feb\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(03|Mar\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(04|Apr\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(05|May\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(06|Jun\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(07|Jul\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(08|Aug\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(09|Sep\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(10|Oct\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(11|Nov\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(12|Dec\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
```

Comment: Of course, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've edited the question and added an input example, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to GNU `date` (the default on Linux systems), you can do:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)-([a-z]+)(.+)/\2\3-\1/i' file | 
    while read d; do date -d "$d" +%d/%m/%y; done
24/12/16
24/12/16
```

That changes lines like `2016-Dec-24` to `Dec-24-2016` (a format that GNU `date` can understand), leaves lines like `2016-12-24` (a format GNU date already understands) alone, and then passes each line as an input date string to `date`. It doesn't do it in-place and it doesn't use `sed -i` but is almost certainly the simplest approach.

If you *really* need to do it using `sed`, you could make a list of all months and corresponding numbers:

```
$ for m in {1..12}; do printf '%s %s\n' "$m" $(date -d "$m/1/2016" +%b); done
1 Jan
2 Feb
3 Mar
4 Apr
5 May
6 Jun
7 Jul
8 Aug
9 Sep
10 Oct
11 Nov
12 Dec
```

Save that as `months` and then iterate over it to modify your file:

```
while read num mon; do 
    sed -Ei "s/$mon/$num/; s#(.*)-(.*)-(.*)#\3/\2/\1#" file
done < months
```

Or, if your sed implementation needs separate `-e`:

```
while read num mon; do 
    sed -i -e "s/$mon/$num/" -Ee 's#(.*)-(.*)-(.*)#\3/\2/\1#' file
done < months
```

The first substitution will replace all alphabetical month names with their corresponding number and the second moves things around to get your desired format.

Comment: Using `date` in a loop like that is inefficient. Use `date -f` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see wrong regex-wise is that in basic (BRE) mode, `|` is literal - you need `\|` to make it a logical OR i.e. `\(01\|Jan\)` and so on.

If your version supports `-e` then I don't see any good reason to make multiple calls to `sed` - you can just chain the `-e <expr1> -e <expr2> ...` in a single call. So

```
sed -i \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(01\|Jan\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(02\|Feb\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(03\|Mar\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(04\|Apr\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(05\|May\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(06\|Jun\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(07\|Jul\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(08\|Aug\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(09\|Sep\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(10\|Oct\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(11\|Nov\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' \
  -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\(12\|Dec\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g' $1
```

However there are more elegant ways to do this - for example in perl using `strptime` and `strftime` functions (provided by the `Time::Piece` module for example):

```
perl -i -MTime::Piece -pe '
  s|\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d?|Time::Piece->strptime($&, "%Y-%m-%d")->strftime("%Y/%m/%d")|ge;
  s|\d{4}-...-\d\d?|Time::Piece->strptime($&, "%Y-%b-%d")->strftime("%Y/%m/%d")|ge;
' file
```

Comment: All those `e`xpression could be turned into a single one e.g. use one regex for "month":  `(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)` (using ERE for simplicity). Though the problem with these `sed` commands is that using backrefs will preserve the month "as is" so `2016-Dec-24` will never be replaced by `24/12/2016` (unless a "dictionary" is used). So perl ftw.

Comment: @don_crissti I'd kind of assumed the intent was to eventually replace the `\2` backreference with the corresponding numeric month, as per the original question. That's why I left the OP's basic format as-is.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r -i '
/([0-9]{4})-([[:alpha:]]{3})-([0-9]{2})/ {
    s#([0-9]{4})-Jan-([0-9]{2})#\2/01/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Feb-([0-9]{2})#\2/02/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Mar-([0-9]{2})#\2/03/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Apr-([0-9]{2})#\2/04/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-May-([0-9]{2})#\2/05/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Jun-([0-9]{2})#\2/06/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Jul-([0-9]{2})#\2/07/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Aug-([0-9]{2})#\2/08/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Sep-([0-9]{2})#\2/09/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Oct-([0-9]{2})#\2/10/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Nov-([0-9]{2})#\2/11/\1#g
    s#([0-9]{4})-Dec-([0-9]{2})#\2/12/\1#g
}
s#([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})#\3/\2/\1#g
' file
```